# Notary node in a cordapp

Tags: corda

I've been trying to build a cordapp with three participants, where one of those participants can act as a notary but doesn't need to be a notary.
Is it possible to build a cordapp without a notary node??

Answer (score 0):

No, you must have a notary; which is the entity that prevents double-spends (i.e. consuming already consumed states as transaction inputs), and it's also the time-stamping authority which allows you to use time-windows in your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid notaries you can build a network where all nodes are notary and each node refers himself as notary when building a transaction.